# Shorthand for an array of frozen strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

For a single string, parser optimization with `freeze` applies.

```
"foo" # => generated every time it is called
"foo".freeze # => generated only once
```

Is there a way to create an array of parser optimized frozen strings along the lines of using the `%w` literal?

```
%w[foo bar baz] # => each string is generated every time it is called
... # => an array of strings generated only once
```

Comment: `.map!(&:freeze)` will work... :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit that's not handled at the parser level

Comment: @Stefan Humm.. that's a *feature* request, it seems..

Comment: Is there any practical use case?

Comment: There's a feature request to add a magic `immutable: string` comment in ruby 2.2.0: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9278